# Blowing shofar at a wedding

Tags: minhag, wedding, shofar

Friends of mine are getting married this Sunday and asked me if I would blow shofar at the chuppah. I have been ba'al toke'a probably 2/3 of the years since my bar mitzvah (2002) in three different cities -- that is, I'm totally comfortable with what to do in the normal shofar environment.

But what am I supposed to do at a chuppah? They asked for teki'a gedolah "right before the processional starts, after the rabbi welcomes everyone."

But:

- I really don't want to be the center of attention. This is their night. If they want shofar then fine, but I can go a good 45-50 seconds. Should I cut it short?
- Is Ne'ilah (teki'a gedola only) a good parallel here? If not, should I convince them to go with a more standard teki'a-sh'varim-t'rua-teki'a (gedola) model?

In general: Have you heard or blown a shofar at a wedding? What notes was it? When was it? Did the ba'al toke'a cut it short so as not to steal the limelight?

Thanks!

Comment: I've never a seen a Shofar blast at a wedding. Probably whatever you feel is best, is best. Welcome to Mi Yodeya btw! Hope to see you around :)

Comment: @Double AA I have seen a shofar blown at a levaya. That is what neila is not a wedding.

Comment: Do a single blow, not sh'varim, etc. Ask them how long they want it - that's for them to decide, but probably go shorter so it doesn't get weird. And blow it right next to the chuppah, so people will look at the couple, and not at you. (But point the shofar upward, so it doesn't deafen everyone standing near you.)

Comment: Are the couple getting married baalei teshuva?

Comment: Not from nothing to black hat, but yes, they are more observant than their parents.

Comment: @GideonKlionsky May answer your question

Comment: Agree with @Ariel - Only tekiyot. Shvarim and teruah are voices of weeping and alarm and are not appropriate to a wedding. You may improvise other notes of course, not used on RH, because the shofar is being used as a musical instrument and not as a tashmish kedushah.

Answer (score 2):

An essay by Art Finkle on the topic of shofar at weddings appears at http://hearingshofar.blogspot.com/search?q=wedding.  In excerpt: "There is nothing on the Code of Jewish Law, as amended by the Mishnah Berurah that mandates a shofar at a wedding. However, music is not forbidden. I have found no mention of shofar sounding at Jewish wedding, after extensive research in Mishnah, Talmud, Rishonim, Acharonim and modern commentators. However, I can guest what the significance may be, particularly for Israeli’s. When the Wailing Wall was recurred in 1967, the secular Israeli Army secured a shofar sounder to proclaim the Western Wall was now in the hands of those who venerated it. Subsequently, other Israeli events have had the shofar heralding something important."

After reviewing other teachings about shofar, he concludes: "After taking part in a wedding ceremony and seeing the quests’ reactions in this solemn, bitter-sweet, tender and loving ceremony, I claim that shofar sounding at a wedding is appropriate. The sounds signal that something special is going to occur. It signals reverence, majesty, noble and royal. And it is authentically Jewish."

I add that Psalm 81 says to sound shofar...during our seasons of joy. I include weddings in that category.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Mi Yodeya.  What does the article say?  Can you summarize?  (We strive to have the answers here, not just links to answers.)

Comment: How did the Mishna Berura _amend_ Jewish law?

Comment: @DoubleAA I could point to chiddushim therein, but instead I'll just say that A) he is qouting and maybe Michael Chussid would have used a different word and B) amendments need not be "it was A & now its B" but can be making explicit that which was implicit or not previously discussed.